# Tem em português uma forma durativa futura?

Tags: verbos, tempo-verbal

Estou aprendendo português há alguns meses e agora me pergunto se português tem a possibilidade de dizer que uma ação é futura e durativa, uma coisa como "está dormindo" ou "estava dormindo" mas no futuro. Vocês sabem se tem?

Comment: Se a frase não tiver detalhes que restrinjam a ação no futuro, como data/hora, um tempo limite em que a ação ocorrerá, o sentido do futuro no geral é indeterminado, não tem fim, é durativo: "Esperarei" (para sempre), "Correrei 5 kilômetros" (a ação termina em 5 km). Contudo ainda há as formações de futuro com o gerúndio e o infinitivo gerundivo, que em geral dão ênfase a ações em andamento, repetitivas,e/ou que iniciarão no futuro, normalmente sob condições.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, tem. Por exemplo:

> Quando você chegar, eu *estarei esperando* por você.

Ou, em português europeu:

> Quando você chegar, eu "*estarei a esperar* por si."

Vale notar também que o uso abusivo desse tempo (ou do gerúndio em geral) recebe o nome de [gerundismo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/endorreia). Por exemplo "Em breve *estaremos retornando* sua ligação." pode ser melhor expresso com o futuro ou mesmo o presente ("Em breve *retornaremos/retornamos* sua ligação.").

Comment: Em português europeu: "Quando você chegar, eu estarei a esperar por si."

Comment: @ANeves Sim, eu pensei em adicionar um comentário a respeito, mas não quis correr o risco de errar (e teria mesmo: não teria lembrado do "por si"). Confirmando: o sentido é exatamente o mesmo do da expressão em pt-br, ou (como soa aos meus ouvidos) ele transmite um menor sentido de continuidade (ou seja, como se estive mais próximo de "eu vou esperar por si")?

Comment: @stafusa Mesma coisa, simplesmente para este exemplo seria bem mais idiomático _Estarei à sua espera quando chegar_ ou _Quando chegar, já eu estarei/estarei eu à sua espera_, dependendo do que se quer focar.

Comment: Sim, a versão do Artefacto está muito melhor; a minha agora soa-me estranha. O português tem muito que se lhe diga...

Comment: @ANeves Sim, também acho, mas mantenho a sua para me ater ao escopo da pergunta.